# MongoDB and node.js store custom JSON

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a API that needs to respond with a specific "json" structure that is looking exactly like a response from a other API.

My question is how I can store this in MongoDB and in the end replay with a this custom json document.

I need the response to look exactly like this:

```
[{
    "number": "510616221626",
    "date": "2013-12-02T00:00:00+01:00",
    "groupType": "D",
    "type": "I",
    "amount": "35200"
}, {
    "number": "510447942721",
    "date": "2013-11-02T00:00:00+01:00",
    "groupType": "D",
    "type": "I",
    "amount": "35100",
}, {
    "number": "509469895726",
    "date": "2013-05-02T00:00:00+02:00",
    "groupType": "D",
    "type": "I",
    "amount": "41700",
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you have `mongoose` in your tags, here my test with `mongoose`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('localhost', 'test');

var myJson = [{
    "number": "510616221626",
    "date": "2013-12-02T00:00:00+01:00",
    "groupType": "D",
    "type": "I",
    "amount": "35200"
}, {
    "number": "510447942721",
    "date": "2013-11-02T00:00:00+01:00",
    "groupType": "D",
    "type": "I",
    "amount": "35100",
}];

var MySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    // use select: false to remove these default fields
    _id: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, auto: true, select: false},
    __v: {type: Number, select: false},

    number: { type: String, unique: true },
    date: Date,
    groupType: String,
    type: String,
    amount: Number
});

MyModel = mongoose.model('MyModel', MySchema);

// create or save to collection
MyModel.create(myJson, callback);

// then find then stringify then print
function callback(err, docs) {

    MyModel.find({}).exec(function (err, docs) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(docs, null, 2));
    });
}
```

Ouput string:

```
[
  {
    "number": "510616221626",
    "date": "2013-12-01T23:00:00.000Z",
    "groupType": "D",
    "type": "I",
    "amount": 35200
  },
  {
    "number": "509469895726",
    "date": "2013-05-01T22:00:00.000Z",
    "groupType": "D",
    "type": "I",
    "amount": 41700
  }
]
```

Edit:

I forgot adding `auto: true` to schema

```
_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, auto: true, select: false },
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried something like that before but didnt get it to work.
And when i try your code above I only get output: []

Comment: I forgot `'auto': true`, so mongo require us to add _id before creating the docs

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define a json structure in MongoDB itself. MongoDB takes the json document as given. You may be able to define a document structure with your ORM.